# Request an affidavit "just in case"

Tags: evidence, rules-of-evidence

Suppose I believe person A to have a certain pattern of behavior. I also believe that person B has direct experience with said behavior. I, as a non-lawyer with no connection to the legal system whatsoever, want documentation of this behavior as I believe it may be illegal. May I reach out to person B requesting their account in the form of an affidavit so that I have evidence "on hand" while figuring out whether there is anything to pursue? If not, is there an acceptable alternative way to document their experience?

Comment: If anyone could tell me why this was downvoted (for future reference) that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

An affidavit is not admissible evidence in court unless a specific exception to the hearsay rule applies. And, when affidavits are admissible, unsworn written witness statements are also admissible.

You can also document in a journal, regular emails to yourself, or something similar, your own experiences, to refresh your recollection if you are ever called upon to testify about the events you observe.

> May I reach out to person B requesting their account in the form of an
> affidavit so that I have evidence "on hand" while figuring out whether
> there is anything to pursue? If not, is there an acceptable
> alternative way to document their experience?

Documentation is always good. And, an affidavit can be used to impeach the testimony of Person B if they try to change their story later, either in a deposition or at trial.

Once a lawsuit has been commenced, it is possible to take a "preservation deposition" which slightly more formalities than an ordinary discovery deposition, at which Person B would be under oath and subject to cross-examination from opposing counsel. This can be admitted in lieu of live testimony from that witness at trial is the witness is unavailable to testify at trial (due to death, disability, incarceration in some place where the court does not have jurisdiction, etc.).

**Comments On Other Jurisdictions**

Note also that the hearsay rules are far less restrictive in England and Wales. Affidavits and written unsworn statements are admissible evidence there in many circumstances when they would not be admissible in the United States.

In most civil law countries (e.g. France, Germany, Spain, most of their former colonies in Africa, most of Latin America, most Western capitalist legal systems in East and Southeast Asia), communication with potential witnesses prior to their testimony in a court case is much more highly regulated and restricted than in common law jurisdictions.

Comment: I think the first paragraph would benefit from a bit of qualification. The rule against hearsay would generally only apply during an in-person-hearing or trial; in other contacts (verified pleadings, motions for summary judgment, etc.) affidavits are typically unobjectionable.

Comment: Likewise, unsworn statements are permissible in federal court basically anywhere an affidavit would be. I don't know whether any states have adopted that rule, though.

Comment: @bdb484 Your referring to declarations under penalty of perjury in lieu of an affidavit. The federal courts and many states including Colorado and Utah have them. But even if it is neither an affidavit or a declaration under penalty of perjury, the hearsay admissibility question is the same.

Comment: I agree; my point is just that they are much more broadly admissible than your answer suggests. Declarations and affidavits are admissible evidence a lot more often than your answer makes clear.

Comment: @bdb484 I don't know how many times I've had clients or prospective witnesses who assumed that they could just do an affidavit and escape going to court. Nine times out of ten, I have to tell them that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to prove a negative, but in the United States it is very unlikely that there are any laws against you reaching out and requesting that Person B provide you with written statement documenting their observance of the "pattern of behavior" of Person A.  It can take the form of a sworn affidavit, or not.  You don't have to be a lawyer to make this request.